# Unable to iterate over the "tr" element of a table using beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib2


url = 'http://sports.yahoo.com/nfl/players/5228/gamelog'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

table = soup.find(id='player-game_log-season').find('tbody').find_all('tr')

for rows in tr:
    data = raws.find_all("td")
    print data
```

I'm trying to go through the table for a certain player's stats last year and grab their stats, however, I get a `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'` When I try to run this code. I'm new to beautiful soup so I'm not really sure what the problem is.

Also if anyone has any good tutorials to recommend me that would be awesome. Reading through the documentation is sort of confusing as I am fairly new to programming.

Comment: You don't define a variable `tr` anywhere in your code. Did you mean `for rows in table`?

Comment: Also this just means that soup.find().find() is returning no results

Comment: oh whoops yeah I think that just lost is a shuffle when I was combining two different code ideas. Sorry about that. And alright. hmmph. Back to hte drawing board :D

Comment: `soup.find(id='player-game_log-season').find('tbody')` returns nothing. There is no `tbody` under the `div`. I think you may use features such as chrome's inspect elements. It will auto fill some tags for you.

Comment: @zhangyangyu You are correct. Is there something different you would recommend to check out the code? perhaps just use firefox?

Comment: I am not clear. I don't think you need to change a browser. Maybe some extensions in chrome can reorganize the source code better. But I prefer to just use inspect elements first, and the read the source code using `Ctrl+F` to search the specific tag.@Jack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `tbody` in the table under `div#player-game_log-season`. And your code has some typos.

- `raws` -> `rows`
- `table` -> `tr`

---

```
...
tr = soup.find(id='player-game_log-season').find_all('tr')

for rows in tr:
    data = rows.find_all("td")
    print data
```

Comment: It's pretty disappointing that it was this easy to fix .__. Thank you for your help. Any input on the tutorial question?

Comment: It's worth looking over however I was looking for something more centered on Beautifulsoup/urllib2/webscraping in python I suppose.